# Sanity check for current transformer burden resistor calculations

Tags: current-transformer, gfci

I'm hoping to use [this](https://www.crmagnetics.com/Assets/ProductPDFs/CR8400%20Series.pdf)(CR8420-1000-G) current transformer to detect ground faults of 20mA. Using the formulae in the datasheet:
[image]

Here are my calculations:

[image]

They say

> For best linearity, choose R such that V < 0.8 VL

I'll go with 0.5:

[image]

Now say I'd like to have a 500mV output for 20mA:

[image]

[image]

35.3KOhm seems way out in left field for the burden resistor. I was expecting something around 500 Ohm.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you add definitions to the formula that you used? A link to the data sheet may also be useful.

Comment: @DwayneReid The datasheet *is* linked. To the left of the model number... I'll add the fomrulae

Answer (score 1):

My off-the-cuff calculation is 0.5 / (0.02 / 1011) which is the same as (1/(0.02 / 1011)) * 0.5 = 25,275 Ohms.

I work in RPN, so the second calculation is how I solved the equation. 0.02 [Enter] 1011 [Divide] [Invert] 0.5 [Times]

Yeah - that resistor value seems high but upon inspection, is reasonable.